# Wordpress wp_update/insert_term doesnt work with adding product_tag in woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

after **Woocommerce** update(now **Woocommerce** version is 3.2.5) my plugin which adds `product_tags` doesnt work. I'm using `Insert_term` or `Update_term` and tags still don't exist. it worked before update so do You have some ideas how to fix it? Here's a code:

```
if ($parent_term !== 0 && $parent_term !== null)
{
    wp_update_term(
        $parent_term_id,
        $tag_type,  // here is "product_tag"
        array
        (
            'description' => $textsyn,
        )
    );
}
else
{
    wp_insert_term
    (
        $value,
        $tag_type,
        array
        (
            'description' => $textsyn,
        )
    );
}
```

Comment: Have a look here: https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/function-add_woocommerce_term_meta.html

Comment: tried with it and still product tags dont appear, maybe i dont get it what exactly is $meta_key and $meta_value, i was trying to put taxonomy into meta_key and description like in my first code as meta_value.